# I can't get local ip address in blazor webassembly pwa application

Tags: javascript, c#, .net-core, blazor, webassembly

I have a Blazor Wasm Pwa project on .net 5. I published my project on the server. I'm sending the relevant url request from different devices. I cannot reach the local ip address of the requesting device. For example, I send a request to x.x.x.x:7071. It gives me the server ip address as ip. I want the ip address of the requesting device.
How can I do that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.